# Mystery operation

Tags: mathematics, algorithm

In a future not so far way, Earth archaeologists find on a far away planet a fragment from a long lost civilization.

This fragment involves an unknown operation `*|*`.

Unlocking its secrets may lead to a breakthrough in understanding their civilization.

Can you do it?

If

```
21 *|* 7 = 11

10 *|* 23 = 6

1 *|* 0 = 2
```

and

```
17924 *|* 10751 = 851
```

then how much is:

```
1982 *|* 2010 = ?
```

**Hint:**

> The result converted to the base-3 system.

**Hint2:**

> a `*|*` b = b `*|*` a

and

> a `*|*` a = a

Comment: Are the numbers same as ours or different i.e our 1 is same as theirs?

Comment: I wish they would've found the fragment with `7 *|* 21` on it, too, dammit.

Comment: @Amruth yes, number is same..

Comment: This isn't going to work. *|* is just going to be a series of our operators. If it was a new one, this would be potentially impossible to solve.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Maybe they just approached the same problems we have from a different direction, and their operator is equivalent to some of our basic ones, not by coincidence, but because of some mathematical necessity that I don't personally understand. Maybe they found a benefit in shortening a series of basic operators, and we just can't conceive of the reason for it... yet. We're archaeologists, plus we have an extra bit of information to help our research, which is that this puzzle is solvable because it was posted here, heh.

Comment: @JasonC just because a puzzle was posted here doesn't mean it a) works or b) is a valid puzzle

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Just because it's hard doesn't mean you immediately have to assume it doesn't work or isn't valid. Might be true, but I bet you haven't spent enough time thinking about it to come to that conclusion for sure. I'm more optimistic, personally. :)

Comment: @JasonC, this question has been bugging me for the last hour. And i don't mean it isn't going to work. I phrased that wrong. I meant it isn't going to work like the OP intended it to

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil It was only posted 30 minutes ago. And also more constraints were just added. Let's see if they clear it up.

Comment: @JasonC ahh I might be able to solve it now. 2 examples weren't enough

Comment: According hint result in base-3 ,but 17924 *|* 10751 = 851 how come 8 5 used in base 3 ???

Comment: @AmruthA its base 10 converted to base 3, so 851 is 1'011'112

Comment: Amruth going right direction

Comment: Argh, I really want to give up, but I've dug myself in a hole with all my comments and I have no choice now. :'(

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ok, I think I got something. The answer should be :

> 1960.

The ancient civilization

> had a numbering system based on the base 3, as it has been mentioned in the comments and in the hint. Thus, they only had digits 0, 1 and 2.

The operation `*|*` is performed :

> on each digit of a number like this:
> > If the 2 digits are the same, then the result is the same.
>  That gives us :
>                  0 `*|*` 0 = 0
>                  1 `*|*` 1 = 1
>                  2 `*|*` 2 = 2
> > If the digits are different, then the result is the last remaining digit 
>  That gives us :
>                  0 `*|*` 1 = 2
>                  1 `*|*` 2 = 0
>                  2 `*|*` 0 = 1

Now, the real problem. In order to obtain the result for 2 numbers, we have to

> convert the numbers to their representation in base-3. Then, we apply the operation digit by digit.
> For example, 421 `*|*` 379 gives 120121 `*|*` 112001 which gives 101211, and converted back to decimal : 292.

And now, all the values in the question :

> 21 `*|*` 7 = 11
> 0000000210 `*|*` 0000000021 = 0000000102
>
> 10 `*|*` 23 = 6
> 0000000101 `*|*` 0000000212
>
> 1 `*|*` 0 = 2
> 0000000001 `*|*` 0000000000 = 0000000002
>
> 17924 `*|*` 10751 = 851
> 0220120212 `*|*` 0112202012 = 0001011112

With, of course, the final answer :

> 1982 `*|*` 2010 = 1960
> 0002201102 `*|*` 0002202110 = 0002200121

Comment: Correct answer!!!

Comment: Oh wow... As soon as I saw your answer I immediately understood the pattern... That's frustrating :P

Comment: Good job sir.... I'm very impressed that you solved this problem. but How?

Comment: @Smart I'm not sure if you asked me, but in case you did (to prove I didn't lie in my comment :P): **[ROT13](http://www.rot13.com/)** Pbaireg rnpu cneg gb onfr guerr gura pbzcner gur gjb cnegf (yrnqvat mrebf) pbyhza-jvfr. Vs gurl ner gjb qvssrerag inyhrf, pubbfr gur erznvavat bar. Vs gurer ner gur fnzr ahzoref, pubbfr gung ahzore.

Comment: @Smart As soon as you said it was base-3, I knew it was something to do with the remaining digit when you compute the two first ones together. So, I tried to build something with that and it worked :)

Comment: @LukasRotter Exaclty! Good job to you :)

Comment: Good job! I ended up giving up after all, lol.